# Monthly probability of falling off a cliff from annual probability of falling off a cliff

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am trying to analyze the cost and risk implied by an insurance for occupational disability. I know that for people in their 30s the probability of attaining some degree of occupational disability is 42%. What I would like to know is, how to calculate the monthly probability of an event happening that causes me to be occupationally disabled and stay that way going forwards that is consistent with the 42% probability until the end of my employed life.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the site. 
Two issues: 1) Your text doesn't match your title (title says "annual", text says "lifetime".   2) You would need a lot more info, because the chances per month are not equal. They go up with age (at least while you are working, but it depends on exact definitions) and they are (in many ocuupations) not equal from month-to-month in any given year. 

Also, where do you get the 42%?  Is it for your particular profession? What if you get promoted? (Most promotions would lower risk, I think).